# isDisplayed() vs isVisible() in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What is the difference between `isDisplayed()` and `isVisible()` methods in Selenium? Both are used to identify whether web element is or is not hidden in web page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer is that `isVisible` is method of old `Selenium RC` and `isDisplayed` is method of Selenium 2.

If you are talking about `WebDrivers` [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html), it contains only `isDisplayed()` method, which by the doc:

> Is this element displayed or not? This method avoids the problem of
>   having to parse an element's "style" attribute.

Before webdriver we had Selenium RC, which is now long deprecated, the `DefaultSelenium` class had `isVisible()` method that:

> Determines if the specified element is visible. An element can be
>   rendered invisible by setting the CSS "visibility" property to
>   "hidden", or the "display" property to "none", either for the element
>   itself or one if its ancestors. This method will fail if the element
>   is not present.

[reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.DefaultSelenium.IsVisible.html)

Answer (score 3):

As explained in this post [How does Selenium WebDriver's isDisplayed() method work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062372/how-does-selenium-webdrivers-isdisplayed-method-work)

WebDriver has its own [W3C specification.](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html) and the section about [determining visibility](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-element-displayed) can give you more information from the spec.

**Selenium RC - isVisible()** - looks for display: none style tag - this might throw a null pointer if we aren't careful...thus to see if an element is visible first check if the element is present using isElementPresent() method. Then try checking if the element is visible!  Refer [Difference between isElementPresent and isVisible in Selenium RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223157/difference-between-iselementpresent-and-isvisible-in-selenium-rc)

Comment: You are mixing up `webdriver` and `selenium rc`

Comment: Thank you @ErkiM. for correcting my understanding too.

Answer (score 0):

As per the current release of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) **v3.141.59** and it's documentation of [WebElement Interface](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) the method `isVisible()` seems no more supported and must have been deprecated.

Where as [`isDisplayed()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed()) is pretty much well suported and very much in practice.

```
boolean isDisplayed()
Is this element displayed or not? This method avoids the problem of having to parse an element's "style" attribute.
Returns:
Whether or not the element is displayed
```

This function is typically exposed to `GET` requests with a URI Template of:

```
/session/{session id}/element/{element id}/displayed
```