# Detect text in the form with selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to write a java script using selenium web driver to verify if a user already exist during the sign up .
when a user access to my website he click on "become a tinze" [image: home page of my site]

then he complete the form and clique on "join" [image: sign up form]

if the mail already exist message "Email Already exist" displayed .[image: Email Already exist]

my script successfully complete the form but it can't detect the message "Email Already exist"

here is the html code of the message that I'm trying to detect

```html
<p name="already" style="color:Red;" class="ng-binding">Email Already exist</p>
```

and here is the code I use to verify if the text is displayed but it always show me detected

```
     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ng-scope")).click();
    int v = 0,i=0;
    System.out.println("enter while");
       while(v==0){
   try{
     WebElement txtbox_username = driver.findElement(By.id("firstname"));
        if(txtbox_username.isDisplayed()){
            v=1;
            System.out.println("Complete the forme");}}
    catch(NoSuchElementException nsee){
    i++;
     System.out.println("Try number:"+i); }}  
     driver.findElement(By.id("firstname")).sendKeys("haha");
     driver.findElement(By.id("lastname")).sendKeys("haha");
     driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("hah@ahla.com");
     driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("yassiryakhlaf");
      driver.findElement(By.id("signmeup")).click();
      System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("firstname")).getText());  
      try {Boolean display =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@name='already']")).getText().equals("Email Already exist");
      if (display){System.out.println("detected");}
      else{System.out.println("not detected");}
      } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {System.out.println("nott detected");}
```

when I try here is the result [image: even message displayed it can't be detected by selenium]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
try {
            boolean boo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='MsgAfterSignup']/center/p")).isDisplayed()
                && driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='MsgAfterSignup']/center/p")).getText()
                        .equals("Email Already exist");
            if (boo){
            System.out.println("detected");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Not detected");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not detected");
        }
```

Comment: even if i write a new mail the messag "detected" displayed

Comment: If the Above code doesn't work Provide me the URL and used emalID will look into it.

Comment: the url is tinza.com/devenvv18 and the mail is hah@ahla.com i updated the post and i added the code and the image

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the element does always exist, but some javascript shows or hides the element (or a parent) depending on results from the "already exists" check.

Maybe try the isDisplayed() method?

[isDisplayed() vs isVisible() in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380119/isdisplayed-vs-isvisible-in-selenium)

Comment: thnks for ur respons but i didn t work it shows me "text not detected"