# Check a defined WebElement in a Page Object

Tags: selenium

My first question here. I hope this question is not already answered. I previously searched if it exists, sorry if I'm wrong.

My question is the next. I have this webelement in a PageObject class for automated tests:

```
//Customer filter
@FindBy(id = "customer_filter")
private WebElement customerFilter;
```

Later I try to check if it's present or not, like this:

```
Boolean test = customerFilter.isDisplayed();
```

But it doesn't work, it says the webelement is not present when actually is not present, and the test ends. I've also tried with isEnabled() and isSelected(). I have to use instead the next code so everything works:

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.id("customer_filter")).size() > 0;
    if(isPresent){
```

Is there a way to use webelement directly so I don't have to continuosly use the id locator?

Thanks in advance!!!

Edit: Looking for a little more information, I found this thread about the same problem, but it wasn't resolved: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1880

Comment: Which version are you using.. if your using older version try to update it and also giving some wait time for element to be present on page is ideal solution

Comment: I'm using Selenium 2.52. I used wait time and it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried using latest version..

Comment: "it says the webelement is not present when actually is not present" - is it a typo or you are saying it behaves correctly? Try to wait for it instead of find, using explicit wait: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits

Comment: Sorry, I want to say that when the element is not present, the next exception appears: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"customer_filter"}

Answer (score 1):

When you use the "@FindBy" annotation, it returns a WebElement Proxy.  The WebElementProxy is a wrapper around webelement, and has a "UnderlyingWebElement" property, which is what you're looking for.

https://github.com/barancev/webdriver-samples/blob/master/src/ru/st/selenium/WebElementProxy.java#L141

How you can leverage this, is you can do some creative typecasting to access some of these methods that are not in the IWebElement interface.

```
if( ((WebElementProxy)customerFilter).getWrappedElement() != null) { 
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your suggestion? I'm new with Selenium and  I don't understand some concepts.

Comment: There's 2 concepts to understand.  First, the @FindBy actually returns a proxy object, for the most part it works exactly like a webelement, but in the case you want to use it for, the underlying webelement isn't available yet.  So the 2nd concept is typecasting.  By typecasting into a WebElementProxy, you can then access some of the properties that are part of WebElementProxy that'll let you check if the underlying webelement is available.

Comment: When I insert your code in Eclipse, it displays this error twice: "WebElementProxy cannot be resolved to a type". And there's no suggestions in the IDE to fix it. By the way, thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Turns out the WebElementProxy is in the C#/.Net implementation, the Java version doesn't have that.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post:[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223157/difference-between-iselementpresent-and-isvisible-in-selenium-rc)

Also have in mind that when you're checking `if .size()>0`, this has nothing to do with either visible or presented element. This collection contains all element in the DOM that are matching the criteria.

My advise is to create a method that you call each time with parameter  the element that you're looking for.